Flutter Isar 4.0.0: Can't specify nullable enum
I am using Isar 4.0.0-dev.14 in my Flutter App combined with Freezed. I have the following enum:
@JsonEnum(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
enum PlayerPosition {
  center,
  smallForward,
  powerForward,
  shootingGuard,
  pointGuard;
}

And the following entity:
@freezed
@collection
class Player2GameEntity with _$Player2GameEntity {
  const Player2GameEntity._();

  const factory Player2GameEntity({
    required String playerId,
    required String gameId,
    @JsonKey(includeToJson: false) DateTime? createdAt,
    @enumValue PlayerPosition? startPosition,
    @enumValue PlayerPosition? currentPosition,
  }) = _Player2GameEntity;

  factory Player2GameEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$Player2GameEntityFromJson(json);

  @Id()
  String get id => '$playerId-$gameId';
}

When I run flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs, I get the following error message:
[SEVERE] isar:isar_generator on lib/core/data/entities/player_2_game_entity/player_2_game_entity.dart:

Bytes must not be nullable.
package:statastic_basketball_tracker/core/data/entities/player_2_game_entity/player_2_game_entity.freezed.dart:28:23
   ╷
28 │   PlayerPosition? get startPosition => throw _privateConstructorUsedError;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵

I know that Isar 4.0.0 is not released yet, but why are enums not nullable anymore? Nullable enums used to work in Isar 3 already with @Enumerated(EnumType.ordinal32). Or am I missing something?
